# Labeling coplot subplots

Tags: r, plot

Is there a way to get the labels of each "given" variable to show up in it's respective subplot? For example, in the following plot (`x` and `y` numeric, `c` factor, called using `coplot(y ~ x | c)`), it would be helpful to have a little textbox in or label above each plot indicating which factor of `c` the plot represents (click for embiggerment):

[image: large-ish coplot]

Thanks!